# CSS applied to mapbox popup not loading

Tags: css, angular, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-marker

I am styling the popup appearing in the `mapbox` using a customized CSS. But the CSS ain't applying to the popup.

```
 var popup=new mapbox.Popup({offset:25,closeButton:false,closeOnMove:true,className:'pop-up'})
                .setHTML(
                  '<div >'+
                    '<p>'+
                      Hello+
                    '</p>'+
                  '</div>'
                  );
```

My CSS code:

```
.pop-up{
    color: #F3F3DD;
    background-color: #91785D;
    border-color: #91785D;
    max-width: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #8B5D33;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
}
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: are you able to see your class `pop-up` applied on the element?

Comment: If you are using Chrome or another browser, hover over the element with the CSS debugger mode on and check what the full class reference to the element is. You may need to amend class name inside the CSS file.

Comment: @PardeepJain,   Yes am not able to see the class pop-up applied to the element.what may be the mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Adding your exact same code to a JSFiddle shows the desired results without issue: https://jsfiddle.net/ag9u8fvs/.

As such, it might be the case that your CSS is not properly linked to your HTML.

HTML:

```
var popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({
        offset:25,
        closeButton:false,
        closeOnMove:true,
        className:'pop-up'
    })
    .setLngLat([-96, 37.8])
    .setHTML('<h1>Hello World!</h1>')
    .addTo(map);
```

CSS:

```
.pop-up{
    color: #F3F3DD;
    background-color: #91785D;
    border-color: #91785D;
    max-width: 50px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 2px #8B5D33;
    font-family: 'Oswald';
}
```

If you can't notice any differences between your code and the linked JSFiddle which might be responsible for your custom CSS not applying as expected, you could follow up with a link to a JSFiddle reproducing the error you are seeing as a comment here so that we can take a closer look.

Comment: I think the problem is with the linking between the CSS and my typescript file wherein the code for mapbox is written.Because when i hover over the popup and inspect it it does not show me the CSS class that i've written.What do i do for that?

Comment: @SSK I am working in an Angular project. For me it was resolved by moving the styles from the component based styles file to the global styles.scss file.